# How to specify when an event should run?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

Having some (dirty old) code that does basically the following

```
<overlay id="slomozOverlay"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <dialog id="commonDialog"       
        onload="commonDialogOnLoad(); myLoad();"
        ondialogaccept="myAccept(); Dialog.onButton0(); return true;">
        <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://myjar/overlay.js" />
    </dialog>
</overlay>
```

Names have been made more generic but `overlay.js` provides `myLoad` and `myAccept`

As it is more appropriate to use `addEventListener` to receive events freeing from

- messing with changes to the source dialog
- not blowing away other event listeners

Here is an example attempt to change the structure.

```
<overlay id="myOverlay"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
        window.addEventListener("load", function()
        {
            // code here equivelant to myLoad
            // find button
            button.addEventListener("command", function() { myAccept(); }, false);
        }, false);
    ]]></script>
    <dialog id="commonDialog"/>
</overlay>
```

Now the problem I seem to be having in trying to make this change over is that `myLoad` requires that the original dialogs onLoad is complete for some of the changes it makes - like showing the checkbox.
Even if that where not so adding the event on the button appears to be totally ignored.

So I tried to use `loadComplete` for the event and noticed no change in behaviour, `myLoad` is still run before `commonDialogOnLoad`.

Is there some way to specify to run the event last, or some other event to use that will be run later?
Is the some alternate suggestion on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really determine the order in which `load` event handlers are executed. The usual approach is running `setTimeout` with zero delay in the `load` event handler:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event)
{
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        // Your code here
    }, 0);
}, false);
```

The only problem here - the window is drawn immediately after the `load` event, so your changes might cause a visible redraw.